# using as.polygons() with patches() from terra instead of rasterToPolygons() with clump() from raster

Tags: raster, r, sf, terra

I am trying to figure out the equivalent of

```
contour_poly <- rasterToPolygons(clump(my_raster > 1), dissolve = TRUE)
```

from raster to terra.

I tried

```
contour_poly <- as.polygons(patches(my_spat_raster > 1), dissolve = TRUE)
```

and some other variations captured from similar threads, but nothing seems to reproduce it.

Objective is to produce a polygon that represents the contour thresholds for the specified value throughout the entire SpatRaster.

Comment: OK, I see -- much simpler, just `polys <- as.polygons(SpatRast > 1)`

Comment: You can post answers to your own questions, if its useful to others then its worth doing - make a full example with some test data and show us how!